# About. Autosomal recessive diseases in genetics

Tags: homework

What happens if homozygous dominant  alleles are present in an individual for an autosomal recessive disease will he be affected ?

Comment: What are your thoughts? Knowing your thoughts on the subject would help us understanding what could be unclear to you

Answer (score 2):

You are talking about an extremely simple system of inheritence that is a single bi-allelic locus with simple dominance relationships. You are talking about a autosomal recessive disease. In other words, let `a` and `A` be the two alleles, where `A` is dominant of `a`. By definition of your model, the individual expressing the disease is the individual carrying both `a` alleles (a `aa` individual). Anyone carrying the dominant allele would not express the disease (by definition of the term dominance and because you define a model where `a` and not `A` is causing the disease).

In short `aa` express the disease, while `aA`, `Aa` and `AA` individuals don't express the disease. `aA` and `Aa` are carrying the allele causing the disease though and might have kids expressing the disease if they mate with an individual that carries at least one allele `a`.

Answer (score 0):

No. Because you said it's homozygous, meaning that two alleles are identical, both dominant in this case. Hence, there's no recessive allele at this locus so he won't be affected.